# How to query dates in different timezones?

Tags: postgresql, index, datetime, timezone

I have a table and index in a PostgreSQL 10.18 database:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
    expires_at timestamptz
);
CREATE INDEX ON some_table(expires_at);
```

Is there a way to write this query in a way to use the index on `expires_at`?

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM some_table
WHERE 
    TIMEZONE('America/New_York', expires_at)::date
  < TIMEZONE('America/New_York', NOW())::date
LIMIT 5;
```

`America/New_York` is added as an example, this query is run by using different time zones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can use the index:

```
SELECT *
FROM   some_table
WHERE  expires_at
     < date_trunc('day', (now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
-- ORDER BY expires_at  --!!?
LIMIT  5;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e1bd83a8d47ec406f39e500cb8d7dec0)* - proofing equivalence

You may want to add `ORDER BY expires_at` or `ORDER BY expires_at DESC` to get deterministic results (and still use the index).

#### Wait ... what?

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)

> The function `timezone(zone, timestamp)` is equivalent to the SQL-conforming construct timestamp `AT TIME ZONE` zone.

So this is your query in a more commonly used form:

```
SELECT *
FROM   some_table
WHERE (expires_at        AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')::date
    < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')::date
LIMIT  5
```

(The cast and `LIMIT` are still Postgres-specific, the rest is now standard SQL.)

See:

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676871/939860)
- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63548/difference-between-now-and-current-timestamp/63549#63549)

To make the index applicable, you need a "sargable" expression, i.e. Postgres must be able to place the indexed term on the left side of an applicable operator, and a stable value to the right. See:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29245753/939860)

It may help to express your objective in plain English:
*Get rows where `expires_at` adjusted to the time zone 'America/New_York' falls before 00:00 hours of the current day at that time zone.*

This can be broken down into 4 steps:

1. Take the current `timestamp with time zone`:

   `now()`
2. Get the according local `timestamp without time zone` for New York:

   `now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'`
3. Truncate it to the start of the day (still `timestamp without time zone`):

   `date_trunc('day', (now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'))`
4. Get the according `timestamp with time zone`:

   `date_trunc('day', (now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'`

```
test=> SELECT now() AS step1
test->      , now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS step2
test->      , date_trunc('day', (now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')) AS step3
test->      , date_trunc('day', (now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS step4;

            step1             |           step2           |        step3        |         step4          
------------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+------------------------
 2022-05-21 19:52:34.23824+02 | 2022-05-21 13:52:34.23824 | 2022-05-21 00:00:00 | 2022-05-21 06:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

Keep in mind that `timestamptz` is *displayed* according to the current time zone setting of your session ('Europe/Vienna' in my example), which has no bearing on the *value* whatsoever.

There are [**two distinct implementations of `AT TIME ZONE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT-TABLE) with `text` input (plus a third one for the broken `timetz`, which shouldn't be used): one transposing `timestamp` to `timestamptz`, and one for the reverse operation of transposing `timestamptz` to `timestamp`. My query uses both.

Likewise there are two (three) Postgres functions:

```
test=> SELECT proname AS func_name
test->      , pg_get_function_arguments(oid) AS arguments
test->      , pg_get_function_result (oid) AS result
test-> FROM   pg_proc
test-> WHERE  proname = 'timezone'
test-> AND    proargtypes[0] = 'text'::regtype;

 func_name |             arguments             |           result            
-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------
 timezone  | text, timestamp without time zone | timestamp with time zone
 timezone  | text, timestamp with time zone    | timestamp without time zone
 timezone  | text, time with time zone         | time with time zone
(3 rows)
```

Basics:

- [Batch update timestamp records to correct timezone](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203890/batch-update-timestamp-records-to-correct-timezone/203919#203919)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Comment: Thanks @erwin-brandstetter, I already tried using `date_trunc('day', (now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'` but it does not return the same results in some cases: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=45a2dd217e7bb8c1f957e13f93bdee87

Comment: @ffox003: I should be interested in such cases, but there are none. Your `DO` statement switched column and test timestamp. Here are some proper tests: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e1bd83a8d47ec406f39e500cb8d7dec0)*

Comment: Arghh, thank you!
I used `DO` block from other test that I have and missed the columns.